# Reset Drupal CDN module

Tags: drupal, cdn

Is it possible to reset the settings for the CDN module for Drupal?

we have migrated our website from rackspace cloud servers to cloud sites. We are not planning on using the CDN functionality anymore on the short-term. So we uninstalled the CDN module.

The problem now is that some url's to images still link to cdn1.myhost.com/path_img or cdn4.myhost.com/path_img even though we uninstalled the CDN module.

How can we fix this? How can we make sure all image url's point to myhost.com/path_img instead of the link to the CDN-url?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, the links are just cached and they aren't actually stored in content anywhere. Go to Administration » Configuration » Development » Performance (/admin/config/development/performance in D7) and click "Clear all caches".

Comment: We are working with drupal 6. I cleared the caches but with no luck. Some images are still pointing to the CDN. I am beginning to think this is due to custom code in drupal somebody wrote some time ago.